# Why can't I use map on Kotlins Regex Result sequence

Tags: kotlin, sequence, findall

I worked with Kotlin's Regex API to get occurences of some regular expression. I wanted to convert the finding directly into another object so I intuitively used `map()` on the result sequence.

I was very surprised that the `map` function is **never called** but `forEach` is working. This example should make it clear:

```
val regex = "a.".toRegex()
val txt = "abacad"

var counter = 0

regex.findAll(txt).forEach { counter++ }
println(counter)                            // 3

regex.findAll(txt).map { counter++ }
println(counter)                            // still 3 since map is not called

regex.findAll(txt).forEach { counter++ }
println(counter)                            // 6
```

My question is why? Did I oversee it in the documentation?

(tested on Kotlin 1.5.30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll()` returns a `Sequence<MatchResult>`. Operations on Sequence are classified either as *intermediate* or *terminal*. The documentation for the functions declares which type they are. `map` and `onEach` are intermediate. Their action is deferred until a terminal operation is made. `forEach` is terminal.

Manipulating a Sequence with `map` returns a new Sequence that will perform the mapping function only when it is actually iterated, such as by a call to `forEach` or using it in a for loop.

This is the purpose of Sequence, to defer mutating functional calls. It can reduce allocations of intermediate Lists, or in some cases avoid applying the mutations on every single item, such as if the terminal call in the chain is a `find()` call.